# Mulesoft Dataweave filter not working on reduce

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I am trying to filter out empty or null objects from an array. And after filtering I add all the values of the objects in the  array to a single string separated with a whitespace by using a reduce function.

The strange thing is that it looks like the filter function is not working in dataweave playground.

This is my code:

```
var va = [{
            message: "hallo"
        },
        {
            message: "Error on Employee Number "
        },
        {
            
        }
        ]

var filterOutEmptyValues = va filter ($ != null and $.message != null)

output application/json
---
//filterOutEmptyValues
[{"message" : trim(( filterOutEmptyValues reduce ((item, acc = "") -> acc ++ (item.message ++ " "))))}]
```

This code gives an error when the last element is not empty with key "message"  then there is no error.

Comment: The online dataweave playground is just messed up. I find it often then it sometimes gives an error for a working code like in your case. If you pass your `va` variable in the payload itself it will work in the playground as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The online dataweave is not that reliable and can sometime behave differently then the actual Runtime. Your code will probably work in with the actual Mule Runtime

From the error it looks like it has to do something with type inference. Based on the `accumulator`'s type (which is a string) the online playground seems to expect that your `item` should also be a string. I tried enforcing the type in the reduce parameter, it started to be work `reduce ((item: Object, acc = "") ->` .

However, as I mentioned earlier, in the real runtime it should still work.

Having said that your code can be improved a lot by adding some in built functions so I would like to suggest the below equivalent dataweave

```js
[
  {
    "message": va.message 
                filter !isEmpty($)
                map trim($) // If your messages can contain trailing and leading spaces
                joinBy " "

  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks Harshank Bansal but when there is an  object with a null value for example  {message: null}  in the array then your solution is not working

Comment: This one is working:   ((va.message filter ((item, index) -> item != null) map trim($)) as Array<String>) joinBy "-"

Comment: So  using as Array is not working but the trick is to use  as Array<String> .  I think its a bug indeed because it doesn't make any sense to solve it this way.

Comment: Again, if you try it in mule runtime it will work. The playground is trying to do a lot of static type checking for some reason, which mule runtime does not do. If you pass the value from payload instead of `va` it will work because with this the playground does not try to infer the type of the `va` variable